# Persist data asynchronously in Quarkus

Tags: java, asynchronous, quarkus, quarkus-panache

I am trying to persist some data asynchronously with Quarkus and Hibernate-Panache:

```
  Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1).execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        @Transactional // I need a transaction to persist the data
        public void run() {
            List<List<String>> myData = myCsvParser.parse(data);
            myRepository.importData(myData, myID);
            myBusinessService.doBusinessLogic(myID);
        }
```

Unfortunately, I get:

```
Exception in thread "pool-5-thread-1" javax.enterprise.context.ContextNotActiveException: interface javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.RequestScopedEntityManagerHolder_ClientProxy.arc$delegate(RequestScopedEntityManagerHolder_ClientProxy.zig:68)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.RequestScopedEntityManagerHolder_ClientProxy.getOrCreateEntityManager(RequestScopedEntityManagerHolder_ClientProxy.zig:220)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.entitymanager.TransactionScopedEntityManager.getEntityManager(TransactionScopedEntityManager.java:77)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.entitymanager.TransactionScopedEntityManager.contains(TransactionScopedEntityManager.java:285)
```

A reproducer project is here: https://github.com/MarcusBiel/quarkus-reproducer

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

With help from Martin Kouba @martunek (et all) in the Quarkus Zulip chat, I made it work like so:

```
 @Dependent
public class MyTask implements Runnable {

    @Inject
    private MyParser myParser;

    @Inject
    private MyBusinessService myBusinessService;

    @Inject
    private MyRepository myRepository;

    private String csvData;
    private String myId;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    @ActivateRequestContext
    public void run() {
        List<List<String>> myData = csvParser.parse(csvData);
        myRepository.importData(myData, myId);
        myBusinessService.myBusinessMethod(myId);

    }

    public void setCsvData(String csvData) {
        this.csvData = csvData;
    }

    public void setMyId(String myId) {
        this.myId = myId;
    }
}
```

And in "MyService" we execute this task like so:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
MyTask myTask = Arc.container().instance(MyTask.class).get();
myTask.setCsvData(csvData);
myTask.setMyId(myId);
executor.execute(myTask);
```

Comment: This solution is not working for me in Quarkus 2.+